# Cannot open data source. .GDB in R

Tags: r, rgdal

I am trying to load the data from the National Address Database provided by 
Transportation.gov into R. The data can be downloaded by anyone after accepting the disclaimer at this link: https://www.transportation.gov/gis/nad/disclaimer

I download the data, unzipped it into a directory I called `data` and then tried to use `rgdal` to list all the layers present in the data via:

`fc_list<- rgdal::ogrListLayers("./data/NAD_20180215.gdb")`.

However, I cannot get `rgdal` to return anything other than an error saying "Cannot Open Data Source"....

I am wondering how I would go about listing the layers present in the `.gdb` folder as well as reading them into R?

I'm very grateful for any help. Thank you in advance.

-nate

Comment: I used [ogrinfo](https://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html) which gave me an error about unhandled format. My guess is this might get better attention over on GIS SE, here is a similar question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184013/read-a-table-from-an-esri-file-geodatabase-gdb-using-r/184028

Comment: That's actually the link I tried to originally follow.

Comment: When I downloaded the file mentioned in that question and checked it ogrinfo it said it was fine where as this NAD file gave weird errors. I think you will get someone more specialized in ESRI files if you ask on [GIS SE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Will do. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Following the suggestion [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/151622), using a full path to the `gdb` folder helped in my case.

```
# check for package and install if needed
if(!require(rgdal)){
    install.packages("rgdal", dep=T)
    library(rgdal)
}

# full path to the geodatabase required
fgdb <- "C:/full/path/to/the/geodatabase.gdb"

# list all feature classes in a file geodatabase
subset(ogrDrivers(), grepl("GDB", name))
ogrListLayers(fgdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

paths in mac are written differently.

https://rpubs.com/bpattiz/Directories_Paths_Workspaces

And especially:

https://derekyves.github.io/2016/05/10/codeshare.html

First you need to set your working directory.

And then probably:

```
fc_list<- rgdal::ogrListLayers("/data/NAD_20180215.gdb")
```

or

```
fc_list<- rgdal::ogrListLayers("~/data/NAD_20180215.gdb")
```

will work